# Движение форм в dephi

Tags: delphi, формы

Доброго времени суток!Подскажите новичку, нужно создать кнопку «Движение», при нажатии на которую Форма 2 осуществляет движение по горизонтали в одну и другую стороны до границ экрана.Кнопку и формы могу и сам создать , но "движение " не пойму .

Answer (score 1):

Киньте на форму таймер, в обработчике таймера меняйте у формы значение свойства `Left`. По кнопке "Движение" включайте или выключайте таймер. Левая граница экрана - Left = 0. Правая граница - "ширина экрана - Form.Width".

В модуле `Forms` есть такой объект `Screen`, у него можно узнать ширину рабочего стола и монитора. Ширина рабочего стола может отличаться от ширины монитора, если мониторов в системе больше 1. Подробности читайте в справке на этот объект.